# Stable Method of orthogonal projection onto a subspace with the help of Moore-Penrose inverse.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, pseudoinverse, projection-matrices

Projection of a vector $v$ onto the column space of a matrix $A$ is given by $AA^\dagger v$. From the [definition of Moore-Penrose Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition) we know that $AA^\dagger v = (A^T)^\dagger A^T v $.

Below is the code for implementing the projection of a random vector onto the space of a random matrix.

I would like to know why is there a huge difference between the two methods of calculating the projection.

```
  % testingprojfrostackexchange
  clear;    
  M = 1400;
  N = 1300;
  r = 1;
  A = rand(M,N);
  u = rand(M,r);

  projLN = pinv(A')*(A'*u);%This is projection through Least Norm
  projLS = A*(pinv(A)*u);%This is projection through Least Square

  [Q R] = qr(A);
  Q = Q(:,1:N);
  z1 = Q*(Q'*u);%This is the actual projection

  display('(projection through QQT) - projLN');
  norm(z1-projLN)/norm(projLN)

  display('(projection through QQT) - projLS');
  norm(z1-projLS)/norm(projLS)
```

Output

```
>> stackexchange
   (projection through QQT) - projLN

   ans =

   2.1569e-13

   (projection through QQT) - projLS

   ans =

   8.3546e-15
```

The actual projection which is given by $Q(:,1:N)Q(:,1:N)^T$, where $Q$ is from the Housholder decomposition of $A$. We get the projections from $AA^\dagger$ and $(A^T)^\dagger A^T$ and find that $AA^\dagger$ is much better when $A$ is a tall matrix.

Comment: Why do you believe that the QR projection is "exact"? None of these errors are actually very large, especially considering the size of the vectors of interest. Even the first one is something like 50 machine epsilons per component, not that bad.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
Using QR uses least amount of 'potentially unstable operations' so i assumed it to be the most stable out of the three. The thing is that for differently (larger or smaller) sized matrices, the projection through Least Square is always closer to the $QQ^T$ projection. I wanted to know the reason behind it.

Comment: Are you sure about that? pinv is based on the SVD which is pretty stable too. In any case, if you're avoiding doing anything "severely" unstable (which you are in all three of these cases), the rule of thumb is that floating point error scales with floating point operations. So working in the lower dimensional space from the beginning is better, which is consistent with your results. It's faster, too.

Comment: In any case there has to be a reason why 2 of the 3 methods which are mathematically same always produce results that are 100 times nearer compared to the third one.

Comment: Presumably it's either a fluke of the matrix you picked or it's because you stayed in the lower dimensional space for longer. There's not much other reason.

Comment: "working in the lower dimensional space from the beginning is better". What is the lower dimensional about the $QQ^T$ and Least Square methods?

Comment: In the LN case you immediately multiply by A' which lowers the dimension of u from 1400 to 1300. Then you lift back.

Comment: Definitely not a fluke because the experiment has been repeated many times. can you elaborate a little on the lower dimensional stuff please?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, the relevant spaces stay the same in both cases. Hmm...try with a different distribution of random matrices, like randn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ has full column rank and that $A=QR$, $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $R\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, is its "economical" QR factorization.

The dense QR factorization in Matlab is (most likely) implemented using a stable Householder orthogonalization which gives a computed $Q$ which is not exactly orthogonal but is very close to being an orthogonal matrix in the sense that there is an $m\times n$ orthogonal matrix $\hat{Q}$ such that
$$
A+E=\hat{Q}R, \quad \|Q-\hat{Q}\|_2\leq c_1(m,n)\epsilon, \quad \|E\|_2\leq c_2(m,n)\epsilon\|A\|_2,
$$
where $c_i$ are moderate constants possibly depending on $m$ and $n$ and $\epsilon$ is the machine precision (for double precision $\approx 10^{-16}$).

In the finite precision calculation, we like the orthogonal matrices because they do not amplify the errors. Indeed, using the assumption above we can show that
$$
\|\mathrm{fl}(QQ^Tu)-\hat{Q}\hat{Q}^Tu\|_2\leq c_3(m,n)\epsilon\|u\|_2.
$$

Although Matlab uses SVD to compute the pseudo-inverse, we can assume that it is computed using the QR factorization. The final reasoning is the same. We have then $A^+=R^{-1}Q^T$ but this time with a little bit more technical work this gives
$$
\|\mathrm{fl}(AA^{+}u)-\hat{Q}\hat{Q}^Tu\|_2=
\|\mathrm{fl}(QRR^{-1}Q^Tu)-\hat{Q}\hat{Q}^Tu\|_2\leq c_4(m,n)\kappa_2(A)\|u\|_2,
$$
where $\kappa_2(A)=\|A\|_2\|A^+\|_2$ is the spectral condition number of $A$. Note that in finite precision $RR^{-1}\neq I$ and the error committed by this operation is proportional to the conditioning of $R$ which approximately (note that $R$ is not the exact R-factor) is equal to that of $A$.

To conclude, both methods you tried are bad in the sense that the error depends on the condition number of $A$. You cannot see that much difference now since $A$ is random and quite well conditioned. The errors should be more visible when $A$ would be more ill-conditioned.

---

**EDIT:** Although it might seem that the second approach gives somewhat more accurate results, it is not true in general. The following snippet eventually finds a counterexample:

```
m = 100;
n = 10;

kappa = 1e6;

while true
    U = orth(rand(m, n));
    D = diag(logspace(0, -log10(kappa), n));
    V = orth(rand(n, n));
    A =  U * D * V;
    u = rand(m, 1);

    x_1 = pinv(A')*(A'*u);
    x_2 = A*(pinv(A)*u);

    [Q, ~] = qr(A, 0);
    x = Q*(Q'*u);

    error_1 = norm(x_1 - x) / norm(x);
    error_2 = norm(x_2 - x) / norm(x);

    if error_1 < error_2
    disp('Gotcha!');
        break;
    end
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last inequality in the 6th line say $||A+E||$ in the LHS?

Comment: @AbhayGupta Oops! There should be $E$ actually.

Comment: So in a nutshell you are saying both the methods are bad. That clears my one doubt and now I can proceed with my work. Thanks for that.

Comment: But 1 question still remains. Why is Least Square method for projection always outperforms Least Norm Method in this particular setting? There has to be something more going on there.

Comment: @AbhayGupta That might depend more on implementation details or just plain "luck" of the random matrices. Please see my edit.

Comment: Is there a "good" method?